# how can i imitate zhider (hides any windows app)

Tags: windows, vb.net, vb6

how are they doing the hides ? http://www.zinious.com/products/ZHider/

like it can hide any window programs from showing up in taskbar and system tray.

how can i do this programmatically in vb6, .net , c++ ?

are there other similiar tools to zhider ? open source ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely they are using PInvokes, you can check out a full reference on [this site](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.ShowWindow). 
Example:

> You can use ShowWindow to hide a
>   window, even if your app didn't create
>   it! Simply call ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);

Answer (score 0):

If you just need this done once for your own personal use, check out AutoHotKey, it has a WinHide command.  http://www.autohotkey.com/.  If you need to implement this in your app, check out the source code for AutoHotKey.